# How to get previously entered value of textbox after project start again in c#

Tags: c#

I am taking price (int) from textbox and use it directly. I want this price to use until user next enter price. For example user enter price 500 and this will remain same for 10 days and after that the new price is update. my code is

```
int price=convert.int32(textbox.text);
```

The entered value is saved until project is running but when I stop project and run again I need to enter again which I don't want.

Comment: You should store that value in database, and update whenever next values comes in.

Comment: I don't want to store it in database.

Comment: Use Application Settings, See the answer for complete details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Application Settings to keep your variables, It allows you to save and retrieve data whenever you needs.

Click on the Project menu -> myApp Properties.

A new tab spawns showing you the various properties that can be set or read in the application you are currently building.

Click the Settings tab in the list of properties.

Enter the Settings you'd like to add (see the image below).

[image]

Let assume, We have a property "port"

To set a value:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Port = "587";
```

To retrieve:

```
port = Properties.Settings.Default.Port;
```

For reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: it is giving syntax error. _Property cannot be assigned to-- it is read only_

Comment: Set scope of your property to `user`. If you set it to `application`, it will be read only.

Comment: now this error. ***Null reference Exception*** on this code `public int priceb {
            get {
                return ((int)(this["priceb"]));
            }
            set {
                this["priceb"] = value;
            }`

Comment: Raise another question if there is some more error outside scope of saving and retrieving value.

Comment: No I can't retrieve the value. that's why i told you I am getting this error

Comment: Where did you used the code i provided in answer, i can't see.?

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default.priceb = int.Parse(txtemp.Text);`                               save on click event. `int mul = 50 * Properties.Settings.Default.priceb;
            MessageBox.Show(mul.ToString());` retrieve on another click event

Comment: After saving value. I close project and retrieve the value it gives error _NullReference Exception_

Comment: Sir I know why it is giving null reference. my point is the above solution is not working.

Comment: To get it easy, create a new project, implement it simply, you will get the exact cause of error. If above code isn't working, there;s no other solution that i know. But, I'm sure it should perfectly work.